# Create a "book"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, folder

I am in the process of creating a centralized database at work. Most of the information will be standalone but there are things that will have move than one file type. I know about libraries and lists and the dangers of folders. I also know that this is mostly doable with managed metadata but I want to compress my things into one thing- I know this doesn't make much sense and it may not be doable. My question is, is it possible to create a "book" or "folder" for lack of a better word that would comprise of a single project that has Word docs, PDFs, OneNote Notebooks, etc? I basically want to create a folder that has all of the project info in it without creating a folder in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Document Sets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Document-Sets-C49C246D-31F1-4BFE-AFE2-E26698B47E05?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) feature.

This allows you to bundle like documents together into a single "set" which can have additional metadata applied. A document set is essentially a special type of folder that supports metadata.

As long as you don't use folders in tandem with document sets, you should still be able to avoid the problems that arise from using folders in SharePoint.

The following instructions show how to enable and configure document sets for a site: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-configure-a-new-Document-Set-content-type-9DB6D6DC-C23A-4DCD-A359-3E4BBBC47FC1

Comment: I've seen doc sets but in my searching it looks like searching within sets is limited; am I wrong?

Comment: @JessicaNall I'm not aware of any negative impact on search results from using document sets. Could you link me to what you found?

Comment: The document set parent has no knowledge of the contents of the children. Metadata from the parent can waterfall to the children, but there is no rollup. So search can find the documents inside the docset if their metadata or contents match the search term, but the docset itself wont know the metadata or contents of its children. That may or may not be an issue for you. We use them and all the children documents have a short description field. From time to time we copy all the children's info into a hidden 'magic search' field in the docset.

Comment: @Rothrock You could always create a view and set it to "show all items without folders" so that it would only display child items, not document sets.

Comment: Oh, yay, thank you. Last question, are there limits to how many doc sets you can have? I have about 50 years of projects to upload; the only thing about I found in limits is obviously the 5000 item thing and if they get moved, 50MB of data. Are there concerns with having something like 500 different so

Comment: Oh, yay, thank you. My last question is are there limits to how many doc sets you can have? I've got 50 years of projects to upload.... probably  something large, like, upwards of 600 different projects. I know the search limits are 5000 and moving them to a record center means limiting them to 50MB of data, but are there concerns with having that many doc sets or should I just think of it like a folder and not something more than that?

Comment: If you are not yet on SharePoint 2016, then the list view threshold (5000 by default) applies. But that's a per view, per container limit, so as long as you have fewer than 5000 documents in each document set, and fewer than 5000 document sets, you won't run up against the list view threshold. You will run into some other related limits once you surpass 5000, like being unable to add/modify calculated columns or column indexes, so you'll want to plan ahead.